# Clearcase - findmerge for recursive branches

Tags: clearcase

I have a ClearCase `main` branch, and have a subbranch `A` created out of main branch.
Once again I have subbranch `B` created out of Subbranch `A` by editing the config spec.

Now I need to merge the files present in both the branches using `findmerge` command.
There are some files in sub branch `A`, which are not checked-out in subbranch `B`. So, what is the way I can have the latest files from both the nested branches to be merged to main branch using findmerge command.

```
findmerge . -fversion /main/brancha/branchb/latest -print
```

That gives only files changed under branch B and not on branch A.
There are some files for which `branchB` was not necessary and files are not created under Branch `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge:

- first `branchA`: `findmerge . -fversion /main/brancha/latest -print`
- then `branchB`: `findmerge . -fversion /main/brancha/branchb/latest -print`

That way, you will find files from `branchA`, and then files from `branchB`.

Comment: whether the merge will take care of the files which are there in both branch a and branch b and over write the old files and keep the latest one?.

Comment: @Bhadrinarayanan yes, if you do it in the right order: A fist then B.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have a view (I'm giving it a view tag, 'other_view' in this example) whose config spec that selects branch B first and then branch A, for example:

> element * .../branchB/LATEST
>   element * .../branchA/LATEST
>   element * /main/LATEST

From a view selecting /main/LATEST, you can then use the '-ftag' option to 'findmerge' to merge from the versions selected by that "other_view".  The following command will preview what will be merged:

> cleartool findmerge . -ftag other_view -print

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers from @VonC and @hack will both work and are fine for just identifying what content will need a merge, in many cases the best approach to actually perform the merge is to merge from branch B to branch A (resolving any conflicts along the way) and then merge from branch A to main.

- from a view with branch A active in the config spec: **findmerge . -fversion /main/brancha/branchb/latest -merge**
- from a view with only main active in the config spec: **findmerge . -fversion /main/brancha/latest -merge**

This allows you to resolve any merge conflicts in branch A rather than in main, reducing the risk of breaking the build for the rest of the team.  In some cases it won't make sense (if branch A is explicitly not supposed to contain the content from branch B), but when it does, I find it to be the better option for no extra work.